# Test apache site on mobile phone locally

Tags: php, apache, laravel

I am using ubuntu 16.04 and working on a `laravel` project.

I have a new laravel project in `/var/www/html` named `myproject` and can access it by going to

`localhost/myproject/public/`

But in order for the routes to work, I found a solution to create a site in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName myproject.dev

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myproject/public

<Directory /var/www/html/myproject>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

and then added a new entry in `/etc/hosts` file, like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   myhostname
127.0.0.1   myproject.dev
```

restarted apache now can access the project using `http://myproject.dev` in the browser.

Now I want to test some responsive stuff using an actual phone.

I tried `http://myproject.dev` it doesn't work, also if I do

`http://myhostname/myproject/public`

It takes me to the landing page, but accessing any other route gives a 404. and this format also doesn't work on the computer browser.

However this works on the computer:

`http://localhost/myproject/public`

but not on the phone.

How can I access the `myproject` site on my phone? And also both my computer and phone are connected to the same wifi access point.

Answer (score 2):

Remember you phone does not know about your sites url as it is not in any DNS server and you cannot fiddle with the hosts file on the phone unless you jailbreak it.

What I normally do is create a new Virtual Host to be used when accessing the site from a phone. But on this Virtual Host I use another port number as adding a port number is easy on the phones browser.

So add another VH like this and another Listen command

```
Listen 81
<VirtualHost *:81>
    ServerName myproject.dev
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myproject/public

    <Directory /var/www/html/myproject>
        AllowOverride All
        # add access from any ip on your subnet
        Require ip 192.168.1
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Then assuming the Server is running on `192.168.1.100` you use this url to get to the site

```
http://192.168.1.100:81
```

and your routes should work without any fiddling

Comment: If he does have root access he can also modify the etc file in his phone to point myproject.dev to 192.168.1.100:81 as well

Comment: @Yeikel Yes but this way, you dont have to `root` your phone. and it's a whole lot simpler to add a port number to the phones browser address bar than almost any other mechanism

Comment: Yeah for sure. I feel that real testing it is probably better with a real domain name than with an IP , specially as you will never ask your user to remember your host IP. Also , for the developer it is easier to remember as well.

Comment: Yup, if you can put up a local DNS Server then you are even more golden. But this works and is quite simple

Comment: do i create a separate conf file for this?

Comment: No just add it after the existing VH definition in the same file

Comment: I am getting this site cannot be reached.

Comment: do I need to replace `192.168.1` with something?

Comment: 1) You are putting the correct ip address for the PC running Apache 2) You are adding the new port number? 3) You did restart Apache I assume

Comment: No using only the first 3 of the 4 quartiles says any ip that starts with 192.168.1 is valid. I assume that is the address range of your subnet right?

Comment: check, check and did dissite and ensite and then reloaded

Comment: my ip address is: 192.168.122.1.. could that be the issue.

Comment: YES. Amend all the ip addresses to match what you are actually using. Dont just use my example ip addresses

Comment: so I should replace 192.168.1 with 192.168.122 right? I am using correct ones everywhere else.

Comment: Yes I think that is what you shoudl do

Comment: I am still getting the same `this site can't be reached`

Comment: Try adding a new VH file instead of adding to the existing one, [like here](http://tecadmin.net/create-virtual-hosts-in-apache-on-ubuntu/#)

Comment: okay trying that.. just making sure.. `Listen 81` is part of it right..?

Comment: I do it that way, but I use Windows. you could try putting that in the `httpd.conf` after the `Listen 80`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132208/discussion-between-mubashar-abbas-and-riggsfolly).

Answer (score 0):

Add an alias on the IP address to your `<VirtualHost>`-directive. Something like `ServerAlias 192.168.1.100`. Then, you should be able to reach the web application on that IP address, like this: `http://192.168.1.100/myproject/public`.

The main principles at work here are pretty independent of laravel, but more related to DNS and networking, and apache configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `.xip.io` solution.

Example:
if your local computer IP address is `192.168.1.2` , and you can visit your local site as `http://192.168.1.2/somepage.html`, in your phone you can access it with `http://192.168.1.2.xip.io/somepage.html`. To make this solution work, you need to edit your apache virtualhost, something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/site"
    ServerAlias site.*.xip.io
    ServerName site.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

**Note:** Don't forget to ***restart*** apache.